# replace a value for a record with a different value in one SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a dataset that I would like to create a column date2, replacing date1 value for each ID with the non 1900-01-01 value.  I know this can be done through multiple queries, but I would like to do in the same query that I generated the first 3 columns.  Is this doable?

```
ID  Col2    Date1       Date2   
A   123     2015-01-10  2015-01-10  
A   223     1900-01-01  2015-01-10   
A   387     1900-01-01  2015-01-10  
B   257     2016-03-04  2016-03-04      
B   682     1900-01-01  2016-03-04  
B   916     1900-01-01  2016-03-04
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you showed what your desired result is, that might make this question more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a sub select and case.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/395a1/2)**

```
SELECT 
  id,
  col2,
  date1,
  CASE WHEN date1 = '1900-01-01' THEN (SELECT MAX(date1) FROM YourTable yt2 WHERE yt2.id = yt1.id) ELSE date1 END AS date2
FROM YourTable yt1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following query:

```
SELECT  
  T1.*,
  CASE 
   WHEN T1.date1 = '1900-01-01' 
   THEN T2.date1
   ELSE T1.date1    
  END AS date2
FROM 
 tbl T1 
 LEFT JOIN 
 (
  SELECT 
   MAX(date1) date1, id 
  FROM tbl  
  GROUP BY id
  )T2 
ON T1.ID=T2.ID
```

Please note that the inner query in the T2 is only evaluated once.